# scala type inference fail confusion

Tags: scala, type-inference, type-systems

After working with Scala for quite some time, I thought I had figured out pretty much all there is about type inference, but apparently not. I can't understand why the compiler can't infer the types for the case below:

```scala
trait LowLevel[A]

trait HighLevel[L <: LowLevel[A],A]

class LowLevelImpl extends LowLevel[Int]

class HighLevelImpl extends HighLevel[LowLevelImpl,Int]

def method[H <: HighLevel[L,A],L <: LowLevel[A],A](t: H): H = t

val t1 = method(new HighLevelImpl) //type inference fails. won't compile with error: 
//Error:(22, 15) inferred type arguments [A$A126.this.HighLevelImpl,Nothing,Nothing] 
//do not conform to method method's type parameter bounds 
//[I <: A$A126.this.HighLevel[T,C],T <: A$A126.this.LowLevel[C],C]
//lazy val t1 = method(new HighLevelImpl);}
//         ^
val t2 = method[HighLevelImpl,LowLevelImpl,Int](new HighLevelImpl) //works fine.
```

It seems so needless that I have to specify all the types when calling the method. I mean It's not like there is any choice in any of the 3 types after passing `HighLevelImpl` instance as argument right? What's happening here that I'm missing?

Comment: And that works too:

`def method[A, L <: LowLevel[A]](t: HighLevel[L, A]): HighLevel[L, A] = t
val t1 = method(new HighLevelImpl)`

Comment: @michaJlS yeah but unfortunately the type information of H will be lost inside the function in your case.

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug. Note that your example compiles fine with `dotty`.